# How can i map control to it's device?

Tags: c++, linux, audio, controls, alsa

amixer -c 0 controls:

```
...
numid=22,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch'

numid=24,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Switch',index=1

numid=21,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume'

numid=23,iface=MIXER,name='Capture Volume',index=1

...
```

arecord -l:

```
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC662 rev3 Analog [ALC662 rev3 Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 2: ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog [ALC662 rev3 Alt Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I have two controls with the same names. I know, that one is handle stream Card=0,device=0, second - Card=0,device=2. But how can i get from my program which control response for specific device?  Contol with numid = 21 or control with numid = 23 handle device 2?

I can find some useful info about it in /proc/asound/cord0/codec#0. But I need to detect in **from my code**.

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: In real time i detect audio devices which presented in system. When i work with them they look like "plughw: <cardindex>, <device index>" . For each device i want to know list of controls that associated with concrete device. I mean controls, changing which values will affect on sound from concrete device.
Sorry for my english..

Comment: May be you know, can it be sittuations when for one card in system presented several controls with the same names, and it's not just back and front  side(like in my case)?

Comment: In general, you cannot know what the difference between multiple controls with the same name is.

Comment: Why do you need to know which controls are associated with which device? What do you need this information for?

Comment: In general we develop video conferencing software. So, we should give possibility to users to use any audiodevice which presented in system. User can choose device with which he would work.  And each device should work without any configuration by user. (We should programmatically switch on all controls, which associated with device)

Comment: Also we need to give user chance to change volume of device from our soft. But it should be very simple for him. For example only one control, changing value of which will affect on gain,

Comment: There might be devices without useful controls. Why aren't you using PulseAudio?

Comment: Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Controls of interface `MIXER` are not directly associated with any device.

The only way to find out more would be to use some hardware-dependent mechanism. However, in the case of HDA, reading `codec#x` is not very useful because the exact algorithm the kernel uses to map widgets to controls is not guaranteed.